# Fragment doesn't fill screen properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, measurement

I'm instantiating a Fragment inside another Fragment. The inner fragment has its layout defined as `match_parent` for width and height. And their parent too.

This is the code for main Fragment. CustomFragment which is inside is the inner Fragment. Its a regular fragment with a calendar.

```
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {
...
public void onViewCreated( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState ){
customFragment = new CustomFragment();
                    customFragment.setArguments( bundle );

                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.add( R.id.calendar_container, customFragment );
                    transaction.commit();
...
}
```

When this fargment comes to life, the inner fragment which contains the calendar adjusts its height based on content of each calendar cell.
Screenshot. Notice the empty space:

[image]
If both fragments have match_parent in its layout why this behavior occurs?

Comment: Remove this in your `Activity` if you are set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`.

Comment: @Ironman I don't have this param in manifest. At the moment, my solution is set a minimum height for each cell based on parent fragment height and number of lines

Answer (score 0):

1. please make sure, your the container for second fragment (if any) is also `match_parent`
2. try give fragment different background color (ie. android:color/red) to check if fragment actually already full screen, but have transparent background. and your calendar view is only reside on small proportion of fragment area.

Comment: As I said, both are match_parent

Answer (score 0):

try to replace this line:

```
transaction.add( R.id.calendar_container, customFragment );
```

with this line:

```
transaction.replace(R.id.calendar_container, customFragment);
```

and add this line after the line of the commit:

```
getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

i hope it will help you, for me it's doing the work.